# Matching values from two arrays, and insert into db if all are true

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I got two arrays, one named `$requirements` which can hold several value pairs. Example:

```
array
  'name1' => int 1000
```

or:

```
array
  'name1' => int 1000
  'name2' => int 2000
  'name3' => int 3000
```

I also have a second array, named `$values` that holds the values that have to exceed the requirements. Example:

```
array
  'name1' => int 2683
```

or:

```
array
  'name1' => int 4552
  'name2' => int 324
  'name3' => int 1718
```

I want to match each of the value pairs to make sure they exceed the requirements. and if they do, run an insert query.

Now, I've done this already by making a separate array called `$result` that holds true/false for each match giving the following result:

```
array
  'name1' => boolean true
```

or:

```
array
  'name1' => boolean true
  'name2' => boolean false
  'name3' => boolean false
```

just to then run a foreach on the `$result` array again to make sure they are all true before doing the insert.

What I'm wondering is if there is any better way to do this? preferably without the `$result` array step.

I also want to note that the `$values` array cannot be edited as it will be used again multiple times.

Comment: I forgot to point out that to be true, a value have to match or be higher than the requirement.

Comment: result is redundant - why not put the comparision between requirement and values in a function and call it twice?

Comment: I think you can't avoid the `$result array step` (_if you could then not_) without writing cumbersome code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check values against requirements one by one, keep a boolean value and break in case a value does not fulfill a requirement. Something like this:

```
$res = true;
foreach ($requirements as $k => $v) {
    $res = $res && ($values[$k] => $v);

    if (!$res) break;
}
```

At the end you can check `$res` to decide if your query has to be executed or not.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! I can't believe breaking the foreach loop didn't even cross my mind..

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_walk` and execute a call back on each array element. Use the userdata argument to compare on the requirements and then set false where the value is invalid. When you loop you only need to then check if the value is not false. I'll edit to add code when back on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the *example* of cumbersome code that I talked about in comment (Note: don't put it in your production code :D)

```
  $req = array(
     'name1' => 1000,
     'name2' => 2000,
     'name3' => 3000
  );

  $vals = array(
     'name1' => 4552,
     'name2' => 324,
     'name3' => 1718
  );

  $sql = "INSERT INTO `the_table`(`key`,`val`) VALUES";

  $sql .= implode(',', array_map(function ($map_val)
  {
     return "(`$map_val`, 1)";
  }, array_filter(array_keys($vals), function ($key)
  {
     global $req, $vals;
     return isset($req[$key]) && $req[$key] >= $vals[$key];
  })));

  var_dump($sql);
```

### Output

```
string 'INSERT INTO `the_table`(`key`,`val`) VALUES(`name2`, 1),(`name3`, 1)' (length=68)
```